# Elegant way for notification when power button pressed

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, notify-send

I want to display a notification for user via `notify-send` when power button is pressed.

Power button has a special script attached which allows to shutdown only when specified amount of time has passed.

In that time when user cannot shutdown the device I want to display a notification which says something like "Please wait...".

Problem is that when I put a `notify-send` command into the script it spams entire screen with that notification because after pressing the button script is executed like 50 times. It is related to power button hardware (I think).

So my question is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your script write a file on hdd ("touch alreadyPressed"). Each other call should check the existence of this file and leave the script. When the script notified the user delete the script. If this is too early, then delete it on startup.